# How can I check if a Google Apps user exists?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a list of Google Apps users in a spreadsheet that I want to wash against the UserManager service to make sure what's in the spreadsheet is correct. Is there any way to determine if a user exists so that the script can continue running without a fatal exception? At the moment. if I execute something like:

```
var userID = "foo";
var ga = UserManager.getUser(userID).getEmail();
```

And *foo* doesn't exist, Apps Script halts and returns:

> Bad request: EntityDoesNotExist(1301): foo (line 34)

It'd be nice to be able to handle this more cleanly so that the script can continue running by doing something like:

```
var userID = "foo";
var ga = UserManager.getUser(userID).getEmail();
if (ga.exists == true) {
  // update
} else {
  // create
};
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use try/catch to check if there's an error and continue:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_try_catch.asp

```js
try {
  ga = UserManager.getUser(userID);
  //user exists
  //... update
} catch(err) {
  //don't exist 
  //... create
}
```

Comment: I took the liberty to add some code example to your answer Corey. I think it's more straightforward for newbies ;)

Comment: I tried this as well, but it came back saying "Unexpected exception upon serializing continuation".

Comment: Well, that's a bug, which you could file on the issue tracker. But that should only be possible if you are using the debugger, or Browser.msgBox().